# bad match error (ibrowse)

Tags: elixir

When I try to connect via SSL request:

```
"{:keyfile, {:badmatch, {:error, {:asn1, {:wrong_tag, {{:expected, 16}, {:got, 196626, {196626, <<117, 244, 59, 53, 152, 162, 70, 229, 186, 219, 103, 89, 38, 246, 36, 164, 11, 224, 43, 25, 168, 239, 228, 90, 222, 85, 122, 83, 166, 81, 206, 105, 37, 41, 220, 144, 145, 254, 31, 112, 70, ...>>}}}}}}}}"}
```

While this request is valid using CURL.

Can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: Is the key file encrypted? Are you providing the password?

Comment: @legoscia, I'm providing password, not sure about encryption. It's is pem file

Comment: Can we see the code that is making the request